# How do I sort a bunch of N x M binary matrices so that the ones most similar are neighbors in a doubly linked list?

Tags: c#, sorting, data-structures, matrix, binary

How do I sort a bunch of N x M binary matrices so that the ones most similar are neighbors in a doubly linked list?

I have a set of 2d binary matrices, and I need to sort the set of matrices in some data structure efficiently so that the ones that are most similar to each other are "neighbors" to each other in the data structure. I don't think a map structure would be efficient, as I have close to 40,000 matrices that need to be looked up efficiently.

My formula for the distance between two matrices is

```
getSimilarity(matrix toCompare)
    //initialize variable "sum" to 0
    //for each rowT in this and each rowC in toCompare
      //sum += max(rowT,rowC) - bitwiseAnd(rowT,rowC)
    // return sum
```

I don't even need you to give me a data structure, all I need is a way to compare two matricies that gives me the result of similar matrices being clustered as close as possible to each other.

EDIT: 12/19/12 1:52PM
My rows represent user attributes and my columns represent page attributes. Each matrix is a representation of what attributes a user has while also having a certain page attributes (for example a user's age is less than 42 and they have visited page 4)

Comment: p.s. no this is not homework, in case you are wondering.

Comment: There is no way to do that. Your problem as posted is not well-defined. BTW, whether they are matrices does not matter at all.

Comment: You post an algorithm to determine similarity of two matrices, then you also say, "all I need is a way to compare two matrices". What's wrong with the algorithm you're providing?

Comment: How big do you expect the matrices to be?

Comment: @PavelRadzivilovsky If you relax the assumption that items will need to be neighbors and say that similar matrices merely need to be "probably close", there are interesting theoretical and practical approaches.

Comment: I think that your distance function right now is just binary XOR.  Am I mistaken about this?

Comment: @Josh The size of the matrices can easily be 1000 x 1000 or more. (not necessarily square)

Comment: @noa By compare, I mean define how one is "less than" or "more than" one another. Similarity does not define that, similarity defines how much one is "like" one another.

Answer (score 4):

I notice that the similarity operator you have on your matrices defines a **[metric space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space)**.  That is:

- D(M1, M2) = 0 if and only if M1 = M2
- D(M1, M2) ≥ 0 for any M1, M2.
- D(M1, M2) = D(M2, M1), and
- D(M1, M3) ≤ D(M1, M2) + D(M2, M3) (the **[triangle inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality)**)

As a result, one way that you could conceivably store all of your data would be in a *metric space tree*, a type of data structure for storing objects in a metric space that makes it easy to look up all elements "close" to some initial element.

Your data has the added advantage that it is a *discrete metric space*, meaning that the distance function you've provided always outputs an integral answer.  That is, you won't have two matrices at distance 1.5 from one another, nor could you get two matrices at distance π

Consequently, you might want to store your matrices in a **[BK-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BK-tree)**.  The BK-tree is often used to store strings, but more generally can store elements in any discrete metric space.  This makes it possible to do nearest-neighbor searches on individual matrices reasonably efficiently (usually without having to look at all the matrices in your collection), though admittedly it won't thread a doubly-linked list through all of your elements.

Intuitively, the BK-tree is structured as follows.  Pick a matrix of your choice as the "root node."  Then, compare every matrix in the collection against the root matrix and distribute them into subtrees based on their distance from the root matrix.  You then recursively subdivide each of those subtrees in the same way.  Due to the triangle inequality, you can search the BK-tree for nearby matrices using a straightforward recursive algorithm.

Hope this helps!

Comment: What would be the best way to choose that "root" matrix? Should I try to find the median? or should I choose some definite constant?

Comment: @user1911333- Choosing a totally random one of your images should be totally fine.

Comment: I think I may end up using a combination of your answer and rrenaud's answer. I choose a random matrix as my "root" and define a hash function such that it maps matrices to buckets that are certain groups of distances away from said root. This way I don't have to climb a tree, and I can get quite efficient lookup times. Does this sound realistic? or am I oversimplifying things?

Comment: @user1911333- I don't think that this will work.  LSH is a probabilistic algorithm, so there's no guarantee that nearby values will hash nearby one another.  Moreover, the output of the hash isn't guaranteed to form a metric space.  I think you might be able to tweak this approach to work, but without some modifications I'm skeptical that it will work out correctly.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, LSH sounds attractive for it's speed and efficiency, but could fall way behind in accuracy. A BK-Tree would be slower, but it essentially has guaranteed accuracy. I guess it will depend on how fast BK-Tree actually is for  40,000+ sets of 2D binary matrices of 200*1000+ size 2d binary matrices, that's essentially what I am anticipating.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your similarity function.  Shouldn't rows be compared to rows?  Also, in general, a higher bitwiseAnd implies a higher similarity, where as for you, it's has minus sign.

Often [locality sensitive hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing) is used to solve problems like yours.  EG, you could imagine your matrices are black/white images, and you want to quickly find similar images.  The hash functions are designed so that similar images will have similar hashes.  So you hash your database of items, and then find nearby items in the hashed space to use as candidates, and then do a more expensive full similarity check against your candidates.

There are even more advanced techniques called amplification where you use multiple distinct LSHs, and then require that some item is close in at least two of the LSHs to warrant a full comparison.  Chapter 3 of [Mining Massive Datasets](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds/ch3a.pdf) gives a thorough exposition on your problem.

Comment: I think that max(bit1, bit2) - and(bit1, bit2) is just a binary indicator of whether they are the same or different.  The truth table here looks like it's the same as the binary xor operator, though it's very well camouflaged.

Comment: rows are compared to rows. Max(RowC, RowT) - bitwiseAND(RowC,RowT) is a comparison of rows. My goal of course in that function is to return a sing integer number representing their similarity, that is why I sum the results.

Comment: @templatetypedef yes it is the same as XOR if you are doing it bit by bit, but notice that for example 1101 XOR 0110 = 1011 where as 1101 - 1101 AND 0110 = 1101 - 0100 = 1001 != 1011

Comment: Locality Sensitive hashing sounds like what I want to do. However, I am a bit uncertain as to how to implement my hash function then. The book you referenced is rather daunting to say the least (I read the section as best I could, but it got confusing after a while), if possible could you explain to me how I could do this with "sets of matrices" rather than a matrix representing sets of sets (that's how the book you referenced does it, but it is confusing to me how to go from sets of sets to sets of 2d binary matrices.

Comment: Here is how to convert your 2d binary matrix to a set.  First, give an index to every position in your matrix.  pos(i,j) = N*i + j is a standard way of doing this.  Then every 2d binary matrix of size NxM is equivalent to the set of indexes of the 1s, eg matrix_to_set(M) = {pos(i, j) : M[i][j] = 1}.

Comment: Sounds like it would be easier to not represent them as matrices internally then. I was hoping to take advantage of processor operations by storing them directly as binary values. But I don't think that I can do that as easily if I have to use the indexes

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the "Voronoi Diagram" as a technique to handle nearest neighbor situations with two or more dimensions.

Is your similarity measure just a scalar (= one-dimensional) distance? Always positive? Or would it make sense to use a two or more dimensional vector distance?

The bitwise AND is not really useful to get differences. A bitwise EXOR would make more sense. If all bits have the same importance you might want to count the 1-bits in the EXOR which would be the Hamming distance between two unsigned integers.

Difference counting distance function for boolean matrices:

```
int getSimilarity(matrix other) {
  int sum = 0;

  for(int col = 1; col < M; col++) {
    for (int row = 1; row < N; row++) {
       sum += (this[row, col] != other[row, col]) ? +1 : 0;
    }
  }

  return sum;
}
```

This distance function could be tuned by multiplying the row/column distances by weighting factors.

Comment: my similarity measure is a scalar (always positive) distance. My rows represent user attributes and my columns represent page attributes. Each matrix is a representation of what attributes a user has while also having a certain page attributes (for example a user's age is less than 42 and they have visited page 4). If my distance formula is incorrect still let me know.

Comment: Your matrices are purely boolean? The matrix cells only have true/false values? In this case the distance could be the total number of corresponding matrix cells which have opposite values.